# Check if element exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is there an “exists” function for jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery)
>   [jQuery determining if element exists on page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257906/jquery-determining-if-element-exists-on-page)

`if(tr)` is returning true when tr is not an element, how do I check whether it's an element that exists?

```
var tr = $('#parts-table .no-data').parent();
$('.delete', row).bind('click', function (e) {
  that.delete(e.currentTarget);
});
console.log(tr);
if (tr) //returns true when it shouldn't
```

Comment: The reason why it evaluates to true is because you get a jQuery object whether it finds elements or not, which is always considered true.

Comment: Would it have been so hard to unindent your code before posting it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257906/jquery-determining-if-element-exists-on-page

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477667/how-to-check-null-objects-in-jquery

Comment: I went with 4257906 because it seemed like the closest match.

Comment: This is somewhat a dupe (I voted to close), but at the same time, I think the question is more 'Why does a jQuery object always evaluate to true?' So perhaps it shouldn't be closed? Opinions?

Comment: @webnet: pal its asked many times... why dont you check before hand...

Comment: @karim79: http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_test_whether_an_element_exists.3F

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Check its `length` property:

```
if(tr.length) {
    // exists
}
```

`if(tr)` always evaluates to true because a jQuery object, or *any* JavaScript Object for that matter, is always truthy.

Answer (score 8):

I always add this little jQuery snippet at the beginning of my JS files

```
jQuery.fn.exists = function(){return jQuery(this).length>0;}
```

This uses the same approach many here have suggested, but it also allows you to access whether or not an object exists like this:

```
if ( $('#toolbar').exists() ){
    $('#toolbar').load(..., function(){...});
    //etc...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because `tr` is a jQuery object, which is truthy (even when the jQuery object is empty). Use `if (tr.length)` instead, which will be true when `length` is not zero, false when it is zero. Or alternately, `if (tr[0])`.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
if (tr.size() == 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var tr = $('#parts-table .no-data').parent().length;
```