# jQuery - how to check if an element exists?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I know that you can test for `width()` or `height()` but what if the element's display property is set to none? What other value is there to check to make sure the element exists?

Comment: "exists" isn't quite the same as "displayed"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if element exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795928/check-if-element-exists)

Comment: For reference, an element "exists" even when it's set to `display: none`.  The distinction is particularly important for form controls; they'll be submitted whether they're visible or not.

Comment: sorry, I was a super dumbass, I mixed up width() and length thinking they're the same. width() returns 0 or false (I don't know) when dislpay is none, length always works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an "exists" function for jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery)

Comment: [***¡SEE THIS ANSWER!***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery#answer-13313296)

Answer (score 153, accepted):

You can use [length](http://api.jquery.com/length/) to see if your selector matched anything.

```
if ($('#MyId').length) {
    // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: You don't need `> 0` as shown in my example below. `$('#MyId').length` alone will do it.

Answer (score 15):

Assuming you are trying to find if a div exists

```
$('div').length ? alert('div found') : alert('Div not found')
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/Qr86J/1/

Comment: Ehhh, it'd be clearer to use .length > 0 , rather than the implicit "truthy" check.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the visible selector:

http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Answer (score 2):

jQuery should be able to find even hidden elements.  It also has the `:visible` and `:hidden` selectors to find both visible and hidden elements.

Does this help?  Not sure without more info.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($("#MyId").length) { ... write some code here ...}
```

This from will automatically check for the presence of the element and will return true if an element exists.

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
if ($('.div1').size() || $('.div2').size()) {
    console.log('ok');
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Mostly, I prefer to use this syntax :

```
if ($('#MyId')!= null) {
    // dostuff
}
```

Even if this code is not commented, the functionality is obvious.

Comment: This will always retun true.

Comment: Oh my... That's true... Thanks for the notice ! Hum it's weird I ain't got any problems with that... I think I gotta spend some time to correct this on my JS Dev...