# How do I test if a HTML link element (a) containing a link href exists at DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to check if a link already exists by it href property in a HTML document before to add another one.

The code is just like:

```
if (!$('a[href*="#businessInfoMenu"]')){
    //add new link   
}
```

Does anyone made something like that?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - how to check if an element exists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293041/jquery-how-to-check-if-an-element-exists)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the `length` of the selector to see if there were any matches:

```
if ($('a[href*="#businessInfoMenu"]').length == 0) {
    //add new link
}
```

Comment: If you have a fairly complex page I **strongly** recommend executing that search within a context (if it's just in a search bar, pass the search bar selection as second parameter), as that attribute operators can be **significantly** slower than standard selectors, specially when dealing with text match.