# Check Object Exists throws Object Required Error

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a web form for data entry.  The page requires an ID to be passed via query string.  In the code behind I check the ID has been supplied. If it hasn't the form (in a panel) is hidden and an error message is displayed.

In the html I have a JQuery script block that attaches an event (downloaded date picker).

```
    window.onload = function() {
        new JsDatePick({
            useMode: 2,
            target: "txtDateOfIncident",
            dateFormat: "%d %M %Y"
        });
    };
```

If the code behind hides the form the JQuery throws an error `Object Required`

So in the JQuery I am trying to test existance of the object [As per this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293041/jquery-how-to-check-if-an-element-exists)...

```
    window.onload = function() {
        if ($('#txtDateOfIncident').length) {
            new JsDatePick({
                useMode: 2,
                target: "txtDateOfIncident",
                dateFormat: "%d %M %Y"
            });
        }
    };
```

Now I get the `Object Required` error on the `$('#txtDateOfIncident').length` code.

Any help to resolve this would be appreciated.

Comment: is `txtDateOfIncident` id of the element ? if it is a server side control, the id in client could be different.

Comment: Yes the id is `txtDateOfIncident`. however the point is I want to test existance so even if it was different I need the code to run without errors.  What I am basically asking is "is there an element on the page with this id"

Comment: Wont this work ? `if (document.getElementById('txtDateOfIncident')){..}`

Comment: Yes it does but shouldn't the JQuery work too?

Comment: I am not `equipped` to answer that. sorry.

Comment: Well thanks for your help I will run with what works!  Post as an answer and I will accept.

Comment: Is jQuery loaded? Is your script running on $(document).ready (http://api.jquery.com/ready/)?

Comment: Ive tried `$(document).ready` and get the same error `Object Required`.  If the form is not hidden it all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better if you set the client id mode of txtDateOfIncident to  ClientIDMode="Static".

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDateOfIncident"  runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```